# Let $X$ be a topology space and a second-countable space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topology space and a second-countable space. Let $A$ be a family of open sets such that the distinct elements(open sets) of $A$ do not intersect. Then, how can I show that $A$ is countable set ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Do you know the definition of second countable?

Comment: Please show your own work and thoughts. This site is not a proof-supplying service (although some times you can get "lucky"), it is meant to help people learn. It is difficult for us to help you learn if you don't tell us what you know and exactly what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $U$ in $A$, pick a point $x_U$ in $U$ and a base set $B_U$ with
$x_U \in B_U \subseteq U.$  Show that $U \mapsto B_U$ is an injection into
a countable base.